# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when trying to run native library?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, mingw, mingw-w64

So I've compiled this [native library here](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/#gifflen) into an .so file with MinGW (the 64-bit version, Eclipse was yelling at me about trying to run the 32-bit version).

I'm able to successfully get it loaded and call a function from it, but as soon as I do call a function I get this error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000672434fd, pid=6932, tid=5628

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)

Problematic frame: C  [gifflen.so+0x34fd]
```

---

So I'm not exactly sure what to make of that. I'm assuming it's some 32-bit, 64-bit issue? Very well might not be, but that's just my guess.

The log file is large, so I'm not sure what's relevant. Here's one part:

```
Stack: [0x000000000e720000,0x000000000e820000],  sp=0x000000000e81efc0,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [gifflen6.so+0x34fd]
C  [gifflen6.so+0x2400]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.jiggawatt.giffle.Giffle.AddFrame([I)I+0
j  org.jiggawatt.giffle.Giffle.addFrame([I)V+2
... (etc) ...
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop()V+684
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run()V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

It seems the crash occurs in the native **AddFrame()** function? If so, this is not the first function that is called, **Init()** is called prior, and apparently doesn't cause a crash?

---

**Edit, source of crash?:**

So I got the **printf()**'s working and can see the progression of events.

The native **Init()** functions runs, no problem.

Native function **AddFrame()** also runs for a good portion, until it reaches this:

```
// ...

printf("gifflen: checkpoint\n");

i = 0;
while (i < samplepixels) {
    printf("\ngifflen: in loop at %o (1)\n", i);
    /*b = p[0] << netbiasshift;
    g = p[1] << netbiasshift;
    r = p[2] << netbiasshift;*/
    b = (((*p)) & 0xff) << netbiasshift;
    g = (((*p) >> 8) & 0xff) << netbiasshift;
    r = (((*p) >> 16) & 0xff) << netbiasshift;
    j = contest(b,g,r);

    printf("gifflen: still in loop (2)\n");
    altersingle(alpha,j,b,g,r);
    if (rad) alterneigh(rad,j,b,g,r);   /* alter neighbours */
    printf("gifflen: still in loop (3)\n");
    p += step;
    if (p >= (unsigned int *)lim) p -= lengthcount;
    printf("gifflen: still in loop (4)\n");
    i++;
    if (i%delta == 0) {
        alpha -= alpha / alphadec;
        radius -= radius / radiusdec;
        rad = radius >> radiusbiasshift;
        if (rad <= 1) rad = 0;
        for (j=0; j<rad; j++)
            radpower[j] = alpha*(((rad*rad - j*j)*radbias)/(rad*rad));
    }
    printf("gifflen: still in loop (5)\n");
}

// ...
```

**The log looks like this:**

```
gifflen: checkpoint

gifflen: in loop at 0 (1)
gifflen: still in loop (2)
gifflen: still in loop (3)
gifflen: still in loop (4)
gifflen: still in loop (5)

// ...

gifflen: in loop at 714 (1)
gifflen: still in loop (2)
gifflen: still in loop (3)
gifflen: still in loop (4)
gifflen: still in loop (5)

gifflen: in loop at 715 (1)
gifflen: still in loop (2)
gifflen: still in loop (3)
gifflen: still in loop (4)
gifflen: still in loop (5)

gifflen: in loop at 716 (1)
*crash*
```

The iteration crashes at 716 while samplepixels is 230400 (640 x 360 gif size = 230400 pixels).

Not sure if this means anything, but in the Eclipse console, the "fatal error" crash print comes first, and then all of the log I posted above comes after it. (It doesn't precede it, which would make more sense.)

Don't understand why after 716 iterations things would stop working?

Comment: What is `s`? Are all pointers initialized? And add a newline in those `printf` calls, as `stdout` (which `printf` writes to) is by default *line buffered*, it will help you locate the crash.

Comment: Well, s is a char[] and is initialized. I'm not terribly well-versed in c++, but all seems to be well. Plus this is a small/simple library I've seen others using while Googling for help, so I *assume* there aren't any issues like uninitialized pointers. Here's the bulk of the file if anyone wants to see: http://pastebin.com/WSnebNmC

Comment: `s` can't be *just* `char[]`, it must have some size does it not? Please show the actual *declaration*. As for pointers, how do you initialize e.g. `neuQuant`? Is the file `pGif` properly opened?Do you check the return values of `fopen`? And you should really check the return values of `fwrite`.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it's initialized as char[256], all objects are seemingly initialized (neuQuant = new NeuQuant() is done in Init() function). Many if not all objects being referenced in AddFrame() have already been created and referenced in the Init() function (and it did not crash there). Don't think it's an issue with the code, like I mentioned, since others are using it as-is.

Comment: Please add sample code you trying to call from this library.

Comment: @vitalyster Added an example of how I'm using the library to OP.

Comment: so, do you see output from `printf("gifflen: quantising\n");`? And please, follow @JoachimPileborg advice and use **\n** in your **printf**.

Comment: @AlexCohn Ah I see. I didn't understand before. I just went and added the newlines and re-compiled the .so file. Funny thing is I don't see any printing in the console, even though the Init() function (I edited my OP to include it) also prints some stuff.

Comment: If your program does not have **stdio** that is reliable and easy to follow, consider writing the log to a text file.

Comment: @AlexCohn After adding code to print to a file, I "accidentally" got the printf()'s working (after I included <iostream>). Edited OP with new information.